# Grafana HA alerting in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-alerts

We have a Grafana Service with two Grafana PODs in our Kubernetes Cluster. Everytime an alert is triggered both instances will fire the alert.

To prevent this from happening, we tried activating the HA alerting, which basically consists of the following configuration:

```
[unified_alerting]
enabled = true
ha_listen_address = ${POD_IP}:9094
ha_peers = ${POD_IP}:9094
```

Since every POD only knows it's own IP address `${POD_IP}`, we are not able to set the ha_peers value correctly to contain all instances (like described in the Grafana documentation). Therefore we still get duplicate alerts.

Also, if one instance is terminated and another will start, I'm not quite sure how the ha_peers of the remaining active POD will be updated.

We'd like to avoid using work-arouds like fixed IPs because this would go against Kubernetes practices.

Does anyone one know how to circumvent or solve this problem?

Comment: Why not just run one pod?

Comment: We decided to have at least two PODs, in case one crashes because it is supposed to be an alerting tool for production starting next year. But yes, I'm not quite sure if this makes sense anyway of if both PODs will fail the same way and at the same time, anyway.

Comment: You can look into a sidecar pod where the 2 pods write to the side car and the side car handles the alerting.

Comment: The sidecar option sounds worth giving it a try. I've also read about Kubernetes headless mode which makes it possible to resolve all PODs IPs via one dns entry. Would that be an option? And if so, how would it be done?

Comment: If you mean a headless service, then each pod gets its own DNS and no load balancing or proxying is done but I strongly recommend you read the k8s docs especially the services section.

Comment: We solved it by opening the firewall for UDP on the gossip port.

Answer (score 1):

Headless service is the right solution. It is used in [official Grafana helm chart](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana#high-availability-for-unified-alerting):

```
  unified_alerting:
    enabled: true
    ha_peers: {{ Name }}-headless:9094
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jan Garaj already mentioned, headless services are the way to go.

If the problem still occurs after using a headless service, it may have something to do with the network setup/firewall. Grafana uses gossip protocols to synchronize the pods. Gossip uses both TCP and UDP on port 9094. We only accepted TCP but not UDP. After allowing traffic with UDP on port 9094 the alerts were deduplicated.

**TL;DR:** Allow TCP and UDP traffic on port 9094 as described in [Grafana Documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/high-availability/enable-alerting-ha/)!

Comment: We solved it by opening the firewall for UDP on the gossip port.